# Consumer and Producer Concurrency configuration in spring cloud stream kafka binder?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

spring.cloud.stream.binding.myInputProcess.consumer.concurrency: 3

I have this configuration in my application, which takes input from kafka and process it and puts back to another kafka.
So, do I need to mention concurrency for producer too

Or what that above line symbolises ?

I was thinking like, the consumer concurrency will increase the number of threads which will consume, but what about producing it?

Comment: Consumer is also a producer. It consumes the message, does something with it and produces another message. There is no producer.concurrency - for that reason.

Comment: @Oleg You can answer rather than comment

Comment: I know, but i can care less about credits as long as the question is answered, especially in cases like this where the answer is one sentence

Answer (score 0):

Although consumer.concurrency is a core binding property in Spring Cloud Stream, it has overloaded meanings when it comes to the Kafka binder. When using the Kafka binder, setting a value > 1 for concurrency creates that many consumers. Let's use your example - `spring.cloud.stream.binding.myInputProcess.consumer.concurrency: 3`. In this case, the binder sets `3` as the concurrency on the message listener container, which instructs it to create essentially 3 Kafka consumers. This has another consequence in that if the underlying topic is not partitioned, there will be idle consumers. If your topic has at least 3 partitions, then each consumer will consume from a single partition. If the topic has more than 3 partitions, then the partitions will be distributed across the consumers. If the topic has less than 3 partitions, then we have a situation in which at least one idle consumer. When it comes to the producer, the record will be written based on the specified partitioning strategy and thus you don't need to set special concurrency settings there. Kafka producer will write to whatever partition it selects based on the partition algorithm; a concurrency setting does not make sense there.